# Resharper fails to debug xunit Theory with ClassData

Tags: resharper, theory, xunit

Recently, I tried to run a Theory test case with ClassData as test input. This is a completely normal behavior and it used to work in the past. The provided code works and I can easily run all tests in **Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.2)** with **xunit 2.1 to 2.4.1** and **Resharper 2018.2.3**.

**The Problem:** When I try to **debug** a Theory test, the debugger starts start but stops before stopping my breakpoint in the Theory test case. Resharper shows an error "Unable to find any matching test cases". As far as I could reproduce this error, it only happens when I debug a Theory test case which uses a class (not a primitive type) as T in TheoryData.

[image]

TestMethod_StringClassData: Uses StringClassData with TheoryData of type string. 
TestMethod_CultureInfoClassData: Does not step into the test case when trying to debug it. The only difference here is, that the test parameter is not a string, but a CultureInfo object.

**Test cases to reproduce the error:**

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(StringClassData))]
    public void TestMethod_StringClassData(string cultureInfo)
    {

    }

    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(CultureInfoClassData))]
    public void TestMethod_CultureInfoClassData(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {

    }

    public class StringClassData : TheoryData<string>
    {
        public StringClassData()
        {
            this.Add("de");
        }
    }

    public class CultureInfoClassData : TheoryData<CultureInfo>
    {
        public CultureInfoClassData()
        {
            this.Add(new CultureInfo("de"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 1**:
If I create a new VS2017 csproj with Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk and select TargetFramework netcoreapp2.1, everything works fine again! If I select TargetFramework net47, no more xunit Theory debugging is possible.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```